# sftp put -r not working, terminal prints "Entering myDirectory" and then nothing happens

Tags: unix, ubuntu, sftp

I am trying to upload a directory from my local machine to a Digital Ocean droplet, ubuntu 14.04, using the command "put -r myDirectory". Initially I had the ["unable to canonicalize path" issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/uploading-directories-with-sftp), but I created a remote 'myDirectory' as instructed and the error message disappeared.

However, "put -r myDirectory" still doesn't work - the console prints "Uploading myDirectory/ to /remote/path/myDirectory, Entering myDirectory/" and then nothing happens. I am new to sftp but I'm very puzzled as I can't find my problem on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Well - I'm currently running into the same problem.
It seems that this OpenSSH bug report may have a lot to do with it:

http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-bugs/2016-January/015929.html

I'm running on Ubuntu 15.10, OpenSSH version 6.9p1. They seem to have fixed it in [this commit from Feb 11](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/e30cabfa4ab456a30b3224f7f545f1bdfc4a2517), but I'm not sure yet how to get it running in my current environment.

Comment: I'm just working around it by using non-recursive `PUT` commands now. I'm lucky that my directory structure is not too deep...

Comment: Yeah I worked around it by cloning my code from github instead -_-

Answer (score 0):

Using

> put /mydir/*

worked for me.